# Google snappy compression implementation in Java

Tags: java, struts2, compression

How can implement the [Google snappy compression](http://code.google.com/p/snappy/) in Java Struts 2 web applications?

Comment: What do you want to compress? You can call the code just like in their examples regardless of what frameworks you are using.

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://code.google.com/p/snappy-java/) has all the details. Any specific problems you are facing?